# How do I grab specific text in between other text?

Tags: python

I need help grabbing just K334-76A9 from this string:

```
b'\x0cWelcome, Pepo \r\nToday is Mon 04/29/2019 \r\n\r\n Volume in drive C has no label.\r\n Volume Serial Number is K334-76A9\r\n
```

Please help, I have tried so many things but none have worked.
Sorry if my question is bad :/

Comment: You should at least describe what exactly you are trying to extract. Is it always K334-76A9? Is it a group of 4 alphanumerics followed by a dash followed by another four alphanumerics? Unless you precisely define the pattern, the problem cannot be solved.

Comment: And it would also help if you told us what you have tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's code that grabs everything after "Serial Number is " up to the next whitespace character.

```
import re

data = b'\x0cWelcome, Pepo \r\nToday is Mon 04/29/2019 \r\n\r\n Volume in drive C has no label.\r\n Volume Serial Number is K334-76A9\r\n'

pat = re.compile(r"Serial Number is ([^\s]+)")
match = pat.search(data.decode("ASCII"))
if match:
    print(match.group(1))
```

Result:

```
K334-76A9
```

You can adjust the regular expression per your needs.  Regular expressions are Da Bomb!  This one's really simple, but you can do amazingly complex things with them.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to find the format xxxx-xxxx, no matter what string you have you can do it like this:

```
import re

b = '\x0cWelcome, Pepo \r\nToday is Mon 04/29/2019 \r\n\r\n Volume in drive C has no label.\r\n Volume Serial Number is K334-76A9\r\n'

splitString = []
splitString = b.split()

r = re.compile('.{4}-.{4}')

for string in splitString:
    if r.match(string):
        print(string)
```

Output:

```
K334-76A9
```